# Laravel: Get all records where expires_at is in the past?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a variable where I get the records from GameMute modal and I need to know how I can only get the ones where expires_at is not yet expired. Its formatted just like created_at

```
$mutes = GameMute::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
```

Looked all over google but its with formatted time or something else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
$date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

$users = DB::table('users')->whereDate('expires_at',">",$date))
           ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Carbon like this,

```
$mutes = GameMute::where('expires_at','>', \Carbon\Carbon::now())
                   ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try where condition

```
$mutes = GameMute::whereRaw('expires_at > now()')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
$mutes = GameMute::where('expires_at ', '>', new DateTime('today'))->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope your expire_at column is a date type column

```
$mutes = GameMute::where('expires_at','>',date('Y-m-d'))
->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
->get();
```

Or if it contained date time value like "2017-07-31 16:50" then you can query like this :

```
$mutes = GameMute::whereDate('expires_at','>',date('Y-m-d'))
->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
->get();
```

Comment: What's the difference between above two queries

Comment: if the column contains only a date then no need to use whereDate but  if it contained date time value like "2017-07-31 16:50" then you can query like this. it will check with the date portion only